# Navbar growing wider than bootstrap column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position `navbar` fixed to the left-hand side of the screen effectively in a `sidebar` with the rest of the page content rendering to the right.

Currently, I have tried to split the page into two using bootstrap columns like so:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


/********************************************
*                                           *
*                                           *
*               WRAPPERS                    *
*                                           *
*                                           *
********************************************/

#sidebarWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


/********************************************
*                                           *
*                                           *
*             SIDEBAR NAV STYLE             *
*                                           *
*                                           *
********************************************/

.sidebar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar-nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/********************************************
*                                           *
*                                           *
*                  DIV STYLE                *
*                                           *
*                                           *
********************************************/

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/********************************************
*                                           *
*                                           *
*              PAGE BODY STYLE              *
*                                           *
*                                           *
********************************************/

.header {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.contentBody {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="sidebarWrapper">
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
          <li>
            <a class="firstChild" href="/">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="contentBody">
        <h1>Content</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, as you can see from the snippet my `navbar` seems to brute force over any bootstrap column restrictions and takes the width of the whole page.

How can I prevent it from doing so, so that it takes 100% of the width of the bootstrap column but no more and no less?

Comment: You will need to set an explicit width on the navbar - it can be a pixel unit or percentage, but keep in mind that a percentage is relative to the width of the viewport. This is because fixed position elements are taken out of the document flow, so their dimensions are calculated relative to the viewport, rather than their parent element. Also, you may want to remove the right:0 declaration, which is stretching the navbar to the width of the viewport.

Comment: @JonathanNicol so I'm going to struggle to get the navbar to take all of the width of the bootstrap column?

Comment: It won't assume the width on its own, but in your demo the column has  a width of 16.66666667%, so if you set the navbar to the same width then they should match.

Comment: I have reworked my comments as an answer, since in my opinon the other answers do not solve your problem (they don't seem to consider the fact that the navbar needs to have fixed positioning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the navbar has fixed position it no longer has an inherent width (the only reason it has any width at all in your demo is due to a `right:0`; declaration in `.navbar-fixed-top`).

If you want the navbar's width to match the column width then you will need to set an explicit width on it. It can be a pixel unit or percentage, but keep in mind that a percentage is relative to the width of the viewport. This is because fixed position elements are taken out of the document flow, so their dimensions are calculated relative to the viewport, rather than their parent element.

In your demo the column width you are trying to match is defined as a 16.66666667% (when the viewport is wider than 1200px), so if you set the navbar to the same width then they should match.

Note: Bootstrap may have native methods for defining the dimensions of a fixed position navbar/element. I am not intimately familiar with Bootstrap so I am answering from a general CSS standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your id have 100% height inside the css, I think you should change it to width:100% instead.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="sidebarWrapper">

#sidebarWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: The fixed position navbar will still be 100% of the width of the viewport, whereas I believe the goal is for it to be the width of its container (.col-lg-2).

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 changes you need to make to fix your problem.

First point to a working bootstrap stylesheet:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Secondly, don't use large bootstrap columns without supporting lesser screen sizes as well. To get your desired result however (and using Bootstrap 4), change to:

```
...<div class="col-2">...
...<div class="col-10">...
```